# AWS - Not able to enable AWS Inspector in us-west 2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-inspector

We are not able to enable AWS inspector in our account in us-west-2. Our observation is that we are able to enable it in the other regions.

We use cloudformation to setup the infrastructure. Looking at the error we thought that this might be due to some conflicting stacks/stacksets in our account. So, we went ahead and deleted all those. However, even after a day, the issue still persists.

We are getting following error message -

```
Two state changes cannot be made at the same time. Wait till current status change completes.
```

Has anyone faced this issue? Is there a way to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

amazon inspector need some policies to be enabled , first

- go to IAM policy
- choose create new policy
- choose inspector2 as the service
- choose the action BatchGetAccountStatus the next
- attach the new policy to your user account
- if not enabled see the needed permission in inspector landing page and make this steps for add this permission